# How to merge lists that contains recursive common attribute

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming

The input is `List(1,2), List(3,4), List(1000), List(5,6), List(100, 1,3), List(99, 4, 5)`.

The expected output is: `List(1,2,3,4,5,6,99,100), List(1000)`

I try to use `foldLeft`, but I find out one loop `O(n)` would be missing some elements. I wonder is there a way a Scala collection api or method I can use to solve this puzzle ? Also, I prefer to be more functional if it is possible.

```
def merge(lists: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {
   ???
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please don't use greetings in posts [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/230282)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function. It works well over huge lists also

```
def merge(input: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {

  val sets: Set[Set[Int]] = input.map(_.toSet).toSet

  def hasIntersect(set: Set[Int]): Boolean =
    sets.count(set.intersect(_).nonEmpty) > 1

  val (merged, rejected) = sets partition hasIntersect
  List(merged.flatten, rejected.flatten).map(_.toList.sorted)
}

merge(List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(1000), List(5, 6), List(100, 1, 3), List(99, 4, 5)))
```

You will get the result in the format

```
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 99, 100), List(1000))
```

Please let me know if you have any further doubts. I would be happy to clarify them.

Comment: Upvote answer. Nice usage for `intersect`, `count` and `partition`. It is working for normal cases but there are edge cases like: List(List(1,2), List(3,4)) ? In this case, there is no merge and it would be flatten anyway (wrong merge) . 

I changed this by using pattern matching. 
`((merged.flatten, rejected) match {
        case (a, b) if a.isEmpty => b
        case (a, b) if b.isEmpty => Set(a)
        case (a, b) =>  Set(a, b.flatten)
      }).toList.filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.toList.sorted) `
If you have a better fix, please edit answer :)

Comment: Thanks @Cloudtech I will try some modifications to the above function and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is `filter`, `toSet` and `sorted` function calls as

```
def merge(lists: List[List[Int]]): List[List[Int]] = {
  val flattenedList = lists.flatten
  val repeatedList = lists.filter(list => list.map(x => flattenedList.count(_ == x) > 1).contains(true))
  val notRepeatedList = lists.diff(repeatedList)
  List(repeatedList.flatten.toSet.toList.sorted) ++ notRepeatedList
}
```

and then calling the `merge` function as

```
val lists = List(List(1,2), List(3,4), List(1000), List(5,6), List(100, 1,3), List(99, 4, 5))

println(merge(lists))
```

would give you

```
List(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 99, 100), List(1000))
```

Comment: I guess checking size is not right. What happen for this testing data. 
List(List(1,2), List(3,4), List(1000, 10000), List(5,6), List(100, 1,3), List(99, 4, 5))

Comment: No worries, I guess this is still not right. What happen for cases like: 
`List(List(1000, 10000), List(1,2), List(100, 1,3), List(999), List(5,6), List(99, 4, 5))` Not merge list got merged into `List(999, 1000, 10000)`. 

Also, `list.map(x => flattenedList.count(_ == x) > 1).contains(true)` can be changed to `list.exists(x => flattenedList.count(_ == x) > 1)`

Comment: Yeah, it is better to be separate to distinguish it is coming from different List. On the other hand, I assume if both got merged, the return type (List[Int], List[Int]) makes more sense then. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a recursive solution for your reference:

```
def merge(a:List[List[Int]]):List[List[Int]] = {
  a match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case h::l =>
    l.partition(_.intersect(h)!=Nil) match {
      case (Nil, _) =>
      //No intersect, just merge the rest and add this one
      h::merge(l)
      case (intersects, others) =>
      //It has intersects, merge them to one list and continue merging
      merge((h::intersects).flatten.distinct::others)
    }
  }
}
res9: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 100, 3, 4, 99, 5, 6), List(1000))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I guess this is the version without using `count`. As Chaitanya Waikar mentioned in the answer, `partition`, `count` and `intersect` seems better. :)

Comment: It seems the other answers also merge those has no common members. This answer only merge those has common attributes and leave the rest as they are.

Comment: ah I see, nice recursion solution. 2 small thing: 
1. It would be better to change it to be tail recursion. We can pass `acc` to argument list.
2. I guess it should better to use Set data structure first and then use recursion, otherwise the case like `List(List(1,2,3,3), List(4,5))` would have the wrong results. Also, distinct won't be needed.